# Virtual Reality Manhwa with a weak MC with the dragon slayer class

Tags: story-identification, manga, virtual-worlds

I'm trying to find the title of a manhwa I read a year or two back - here's what I remember about it:

- It is a Virtual Reality themed manhwa.
- The MC is weak and is repeatedly killed by a newbie killing PK'er at the start.
- The MC eventually defeats the PK'er with a team of other newbies.
- Later circumstances force the MC and the PK'er to team up.
- The MC takes the dragon slayer class.
- The MC's teacher for the dragon slayer class is a young girl NPC who seems to be or eventually becomes self-aware.
- The manhwa was still ongoing when I last read it.

That's all I can really remember.  Any help finding the title would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case anyone else ever stumbles on this - I finally found the title.

It's ***[CAGE: Murderous Level Up](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/cage-murderous-level-up)***.

> In a world where aliens and humans coexist, the virtual reality game, “Cage,” is all the rage. All you have to do is get into a warp machine to transport your avatar (who looks like the real you!) into the world of “Cage.” Siryeon, an introverted teenager, starts this game for fun only to be ruthlessly murdered by the serial in-game killer, Natriel Gaisha. The only way for him to get his revenge is to level up and defeat her. Will he be able to make her pay?